# como puedo borrar una palabra de una cadena de caracteres en c++?

Tags: c

necesito ayuda en un programa para eliminar una palabra(word)
o frase en medio, en una cadena de caracteres.

Ejemplo: char a[] = "programa para eliminar una palabra";

char b[] = " programa para una palabra";

tengo esto pero borra las palabras junto a la de en medio y no la que necesito, se que podria hacerlo con string, sin embargo se  me solicito hacerlo usando char,  que podría hacer, algún consejo?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include<ctype.h>        
#include<string.h> 
using namespace std;


int main()
   {
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
     int i, s, j=0, espacios=0, palabras=1, espaciof=0;
      int c[100], cc=0, d=0;

cout<<"Escribe la serie de palabras\n ";
fflush(stdin); 
cin.getline(a,100);
s= strlen(a);  //s es el numero de caracteres de la cadena
//cout<<s;

    for(i=0; i<s; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==' ')
        {
            espacios++;
            palabras++;
            c[cc]=i;
            cc++;
        }
    }
espaciof=espacios/2;

if(espacios%2==0)
{
    for(int k=0; k<s; k++)
    {
        if((a[k] != a[ c[espaciof]+1 ] ) && (a[k]!=a[c[espaciof+1]]))
        {
            b[j]=a[k];
            j++;
        }
        if(a[k]==a[c[espaciof]])
        {
            for(int p=c[espaciof]; p <= c[espaciof+1]; p++)
            {
                k++;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
//b[j]='\0';
cout<<b;



getch();
```

}

Comment: Como estrategia puedes tokenizar la frase original con 'strtok' guardando cada palabra que no coincida con la búsqueda en la otra matriz 'b[]'

Answer (score 1):

> se que podria hacerlo con string, sin embargo se me solicito hacerlo usando char

No te han podido *solicitar* eso, porque eso es un disparate. Pero si realmente te han solicitado semejante disparate, **HUYE**, ese lugar no es adecuado para que ningún programador esté presente ni siquiera equipado con un EPI.

Un `char` es el tipo de datos en el que se almacena una letra (carácter), un `string` es el tipo de datos en que se almacenan letras encadenadas (cadenas de caracteres), dado que es imposible guardar palabras en una letra, será imposible eliminar palabras de una frase usando un solo `char`.

Puedes buscar una serie de caracteres dentro de otra con [`std::search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) de la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string frase = "En un lugar de La Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no hace mucho tiempo atras...";
    const std::string palabra = "Mancha";

    const auto found = std::search(frase.begin(), frase.end(), palabra.begin(), palabra.end());

    if (found != frase.end())
    {
        const auto posicion = std::distance(frase.begin(), found);
        const auto longitud = palabra.length();

        const std::string resultado = frase.substr(0, posicion) +
                        frase.substr(posicion + longitud);

        std::cout << "La frase es: '" << frase << "'\n"
            << "La palabra a eliminar es: '" << palabra << "'\n"
            << "El resultado es '" << resultado << "'\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "La palabra '" << palabra << "' no esta en la frase\n";

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior [genera la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##bVLLUsMwDDzXXyHCgXQoGc6lcOMGf8BFddTEM44c/DgwDN9e5KTuA5pLxtrV7sqyHscHbZG7/f7WsLapJdgYF6InHF7UqYa2c97E/qIoNMPdi1KGIwxouF6qb7XQjkOEENv1embAzmMgeIbqlSEx2NShB1F4Q3hH1j2u8kmnLwfshq0n@cFnMuQdoHa@RT/QKhd71ARD0r2DaGgYBY8i3jRN9XTNeUSLW4/Ze3YSWuFhig52LnEr8NxE6HVfT3GbLXV5otWcviFu8@EgeEJLYcKXWd3soJ5lb57Pm5dqIbdzbj66YLRxXPxbE6KkpH8JsppoXzRbx52JKYcvGSxxF/t6SnHlMjyFZCO2DkqukLaC1Y@rY5Ql3Etv/i4Yx6T3R9/ZZdLXLkXYbKCShc67prCGuyrX5nMG7z64ytoHYlkNAlkzGJYnceoq4N@@V3s2BYUD@1QqfLmrH7UgG@haxqJ@xSs/MpItAMk7PUwz6amFp5g8w@OT@tnvfwE):

> ```
> La frase es: 'En un lugar de La Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no hace mucho tiempo atras...'
> La palabra a eliminar es: 'Mancha'
> El resultado es 'En un lugar de La , de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no hace mucho tiempo atras...'
> ```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Has etiquetado tu código como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) pero apenas has programado usando dicho lenguaje:

- Las cabeceras `<stdio.h>`, `<math.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<ctype.h>` y `<string.h>` son del lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c) y no deben ser usadas en C++.

  - Además, las estás incluyendo **y no las usas**, si no las usas: no las incluyas.
- La cabecera `<conio.h>` no es estándar C, y además no la usas. Si no la usas: no la incluyas.
- En C++, el objeto que se usa para gestionar cadenas de caracteres es `std::string`, al que se accede incluyendo la cabecera `<string>`.

  - Ese objeto incluye multitudes de utilidades para gestionar cadenas, no uses formaciones de caracteres.